# Split Characters From a Sentence having brackets and having certain number of fixed values in brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

```
Tenerife, Tenerife (All Airports) (TCI), Spain
```

Like the above string I can have any sentence which can have any number of brackets but airport code will be fixed with three characters and always will be in uppercase, please provide me regular expression in JavaScript for this.

```
Tenerife, Tenerife (All Airports) (TCI), Spain
```

Output : `TCI`

```
New Delhi, Indira Gandhi Intl (DEL), India
```

Output : `DEL`

I want the outputs as above.

Comment: `str.match(/([A-Z]{3}),/)[1]` should work

Comment: Please post your attempts.

Comment: `str.match(/\(([A-Z]{3})\)/)`

Comment: /\(([A-Z]{3})\)/ this worked for me can you set uppercase check as well to this?

Comment: @RajeshKumarYadav that regex will match any `(BCZ)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
\b[A-Z]{3}(?=\),\s*\S+$)
```

If the format is fixed then this should do it.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/75).

Comment: nice, but this would also match NSE in `Tenerife, Tenerife (Including NONSENSE) (TCI), Spain`. Why not surrounding in `\( \)`?

Comment: @flaschenpost it wont...there's no need see here https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/74

Comment: Ah, OK, you look for the comma and whitespace too, of course. It was `Tenerife, Tenerife (no real ABBREV), Spain` would highlight REV. But then probably the input is wrong.

Comment: @flaschenpost that would be wrong input....newaz now it wont see here https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/75

Comment: str.match(/[A-Z]{3}(?=\),\s*\S+$)/); Worked fine thanks guys and thanks stack overflow :)

Comment: @RajeshKumarYadav do accept by clicking the green arrow.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex :

```
.*(\([A-Z]*\)).*
```

demo at :

> https://regex101.com/r/bA7eS9/1

Comment: Why do I need the `.*` at the beginning and end?

Comment: .* will select everything till the time '(\([A-Z]*\))' part of regex is not matched .  .* at the end is to select everything after '(\([A-Z]*\))' . Without .* also it will work and will select last occurrence of '(\([A-Z]*\))'.